# Create a Custom Block from Observer in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to write an Observer to show a products block at the bottom of Product details page.

So, I have already written capturing the event '**catalog_product_load_after**'. But I need to create a Custom Block which can be called through getChildHtml() in product details page.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't need an observer at all if the event you're waiting to fire is simply for the product details / view page to load? I might be wrong but please provide the context and gist of what you want to happen.

I assume you want to add a static block to the bottom of a product's view? If so, no need to add an observer.

To use `getChildHtml('block_name')`, you need to define it in your theme's **catalog.xml**. Add the following within `<reference name="content">` of the layout handle `catalog_product_view`:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="block_name">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_identifier</block_id></action>
</block>
```

Then, in your product view.phtml, you can add:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('block_name'); ?>
```

in the place you want it to appear.

Comment: David, Thanks for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3401141 no problem - hope it helps. Is my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: YEs, you changed the way I was thinking to solve the problem ... Thanks

Comment: @user3401141 glad to help. Please accept an answer if it helps you so others may find it in the future.